# prefix autocomplete suggestion elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete

I am trying to implement a prefix auto complete feature using ElasticSearch, here is my mapping for the suggest field:

```
PUT vdpinfo
{
    "mappings": {
        "details" : {
            "properties" : {
                "suggest" : {
                    "type" : "completion"
                },
                "title": {
                  "type": "keyword"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I indexed some data with both single word and double words(bigram), such as:

```
{"suggest": "leather"}
```

And also:

```
{"suggest": "leather seats"}
{"suggest": "2 leather"}
```

And my search query is like this:

```
GET /vdpinfo/details/_search
{
        "suggest": {
            "feature-suggest": {
                "prefix": "leather",
                "completion": {
                    "field": "suggest"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But the result returns both `{"suggest": "leather"}` and `{"suggest": "2 leather"}`, and more importantly, `{"suggest": "2 leather"}` is ranked higher than `leather`.

My question is why the `2 leather` gets returned, why doesn't it just do `prefix` autocomplete as in the query. `prefix: leather`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the default analyzer that is used for analyzing your data is the [`simple`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-simple-analyzer.html) analyzer, which simply breaks text into terms whenever it encounters a character which is not a letter, so `2 leather` is actually indexed as `leather`, hence why that result is showing (and also why it is showing first).

The reason they are using the `simple` analyzer by default instead of the `standard` one is to not provide suggestion based on stop words ([explanation here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html)).

So if you use the `standard` analyzer instead, you won't get any suggestion for `2 leather`

```
PUT vdpinfo
{
    "mappings": {
        "details" : {
            "properties" : {
                "suggest" : {
                    "type" : "completion",
                    "analyzer" : "standard"
                },
                "title": {
                  "type": "keyword"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked nicely. Thanks very much for the explanation.